# How do I format Django form CharFields to be next to each other one the same line?

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

Currently, I'm using a the Django Form class to create a form. I'm trying to make it so that all of the CharField fields have their own row, except for a few specific one's that I would like to share a row.

These are the CharFields I currently have:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    example_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    example_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    example_3= forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MetadataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['example_1'].widget.attrs['style']  = 'width:15%;'
    self.fields['example_2'].widget.attrs['style']  = 'width:15%;'
    self.fields['example_3'].widget.attrs['style']  = 'width:15%;'
```

Here is how they're rendered in the HTML:

```
<label for="id_example_1">Example 1:</label>
<input type="text" name="example_1" maxlength="20" style="width:15%;" id="id_example_1">
<label for="id_example_2">Example 2:</label>
<input type="text" name="example_2" maxlength="20" style="width:15%;" id="id_example_2">
<label for="id_example_3">Example 3:</label>
<input type="text" name="example_3" maxlength="20" style="width:15%;" id="id_example_3">
```

In an attempt to format example_1 and example_2 on the same line, I tried floating the labels to the left and then adding space between them by increasing the margin:

```
#example_1, #example_2, #example_3 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

However, this formats the boxes very oddly and it also doesn't do anything for the labels. I'm not sure how to reference the labels since they don't have id values I can use. If there's a way in which I can format example 2 and 3 on the same line, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

just manually render it according to your needs like so e.g.:

```
..
<div class="form-wrapper">
   {% for field in form %}
   <div class="field-wrapper">
       <div class="field-label">{{ field.label }}</div>
       <div class="field-input">{{ field.input }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
...
```

and CSS

```
.form-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried something very similar but I'm getting odd results. I added the code that added the query to the HTML and how I tried to integrate your suggestion. Is that what what you meant?

Comment: you can also get a similar result with boostrap, @JSRB shown the right way to go.

sort of: 

<div class="col">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'your_url %}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label class="form-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="form-group mx-auto mb-2">
                        <input
                        class="input"  
                        type="text"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Carlo but could you elaborate a bit more? I think I get the general idea you're going for but I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: Sure @JohnGreen, the idea is to manage layout with FE best practices, not relying specifically to django objs. So, "decouple" your form from the django logic and style it "the way you want" as you'd do with a standard html form, using CSS or BOOTSTRAP and such.
Way easier and cleaner.
To do that, you should grab input fields and manage them via DIV Classes and such.
I shown you an example for a simple login form that you can use in any HTML file with BOOSTRAP URL